# Ignore left whitespaces on imput in TextField SwiftUI Combine

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, combine

I'm passing to TextField published variable

```
TextField("First name", text: $state.firstName)
```

I want to control imputes: Ignore spaces, if it's entered from the left

Where and how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to do with proxy binding, like below

```
TextField("First name", text: Binding(
    get: { self.state.firstName },
    set: {
        var newValue = $0
        // fix newValue here as needed
        self.state.firstName = newValue
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `ViewModel` add a checker that will automatically check every keystroke and fix the white space at first index.

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value: String = ""
    var previousAmount = 0.0
    var validStringChecker: AnyCancellable? = nil

    init() {
        validStringChecker = $value.sink { val in
            if val.first == " " {
                var newValue = val
                newValue.remove(at: newValue.firstIndex(of: " ")!)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.value = newValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use your `TextField` in your `ContentView` like:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("First Name", text: $viewModel.value)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()).padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a memory leak in the sink for that published value. add [weak self] to the sink. `$value.sink { [weak self val in `