# SwiftUI textfield proxy binding code to ignore spaces not working?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to make my SwiftUI Textfield input ignore *spaces* every time the spacebar button is pressed so that account input data does not contain any spaces.

I saw the code below for achieving this with "proxy binding" but the answer is so concise for me and I am new to { get set }.

[Ignore left whitespaces on imput in TextField SwiftUI Combine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61653848/ignore-left-whitespaces-on-imput-in-textfield-swiftui-combine)

I want the code in AccountInput to *return* if the new input is a *space* so that it does not go into the textfield & loginViewModel.input.

How can I make this code work?

**MAIN VIEW**

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @StateObject var loginViewModel = LoginViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AccountInput(placeholder: "", input: $loginViewModel.input)
        }
    }
}
```

**ACCOUNT INPUT**

```
struct AccountInput: View {
    var placeholder: String
    @Binding var input: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(placeholder, text: Binding(
                get: { self.input },
                set: {                      
                    var newValue = $0  
                    if newValue == " " { // How can I make new values return if a space?
                        return 
                    }
                    self.input = newValue
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we should not return, there should be assignment, because it generates feedback.

It can be like

```
     TextField(placeholder, text: Binding(
        get: { self.input },
        set: {
            var newValue = $0
            newValue.removeAll { $0 == " " }  // << here !!
            self.input = newValue
    }))
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the text input IGNORE spaces? I am still able to enter spaces in the Textfield, they are only removed on entry of another character...??