# Is it possible to make SwiftUI TextField ignore space-bar / space entry?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Is it possible to make a SwiftUI Textfield simply ignore space-bar key-strokes?

I want to make it so that when a user enters their sign-up / login details that the space bar is ignored since that data does not need spaces.

Other solutions I found for this still allow the user to enter spaces in the textfield but then erase them on the next character entered, which is not ideal, such as this SO article:

[Ignore left whitespaces on imput in TextField SwiftUI Combine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61653848/ignore-left-whitespaces-on-imput-in-textfield-swiftui-combine)

I need the Textfield to completely ignore the space-bar.

```
struct IgnoreSpacesTextfield: View {

  @State private var email: String = ""

    var body: some view {
         TextField("e-mail", text: $email)
         // ^ needs to ignore space-bar entry
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this custom TextField:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var test = ""
var body: some View {
    //completely ignore space
    CustomTextField("enter", text: $test)
}
}

//custom textfield
struct  CustomTextField: View {

let label: LocalizedStringKey
@Binding var text: String

init(_ label: LocalizedStringKey, text: Binding<String>) {
    self.label = label
    self._text = Binding(projectedValue: text)
}

var body: some View {
    TextField(label, text: $text)
        .onChange(of: text) { _ in
             //try one of these
             //input = input.replacing(" ", with: "")
             //input = input.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
             //input = input.filter{ s in s != " "}
        }
}
}
```

Comment: If you need an extra filter, just add another replacing; .replacing("@", with: "")

Comment: I am getting several errors: "Referencing subscript 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' requires wrapper 'Binding<String>' & Value of type 'String' has no dynamic member 'replacing' using key path from root type 'String' at "text = text.replacing(" ", with: "")"

Comment: I am sure my provided code can be run immediately without any additional package, unless you modified something. can you edit the post and add your code? another user actually just used this similar code too.

Comment: Ok just added it, I had to make it fit in my app. The errors are at " input = input.replacing(" ", with: "")"

Comment: I just ran your code. It went like a melted butter. Pretty sure it's your Xcode or Target version problem. I have 3 methods for you to achieve this same goal check my edited code.

Comment: The replacingOccurrences worked for me, thank you so much :)